# How to solve the windows7 Remote Desktop License error message？

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008, xrdp

I used `rdpwrap` to support multi-session login in win7. I am currently using windows7 as a remote desktop host.

But, However, after running for some time, you cannot connect to this host.

I was using `freerdp` to connect to an RDP session, so I was able to get notifications of events during the RDP connection, and I got this message.

The rdp error message is:

> There is a problem with your license for Remote Desktop and the session will end in 60 minutes

How can I make this error disappear and not affect my normal use of RDS?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you using a Window 7 Server? Are you terminating the RDP session or do you have several parallel sessions?

Comment: Hi harrymc. I'm using win7 as the RDS host.I was using freerdp to connect to an RDP session, so I was able to get notifications of events during the RDP connection, and I got this message.

Answer (score 1):

You are apparently using a Windows Server 7 with the RDS Host role,
but without any additional Client Access Licenses (CALs).

Windows Server comes with the possibility of doing two administrative remote desktop connections.
When you did RDP to servers for which you didn't install any CALs, you were using the two administrative sessions that come with any Windows server and hitting that limit.

To have more than two client sessions open at the same time, each user and device that connects to a Remote Desktop Session host needs a client access license (CAL), which you can buy from Microsoft and install on Windows Server.

However, I don't know if Microsoft still sells CALs for Windows Server 7.

Comment: AFAIK Microsoft no longer sells anything Win7 related (and that's a good thing).

Comment: I am not using windows server 7 or windows server 2008, I use the windows 7 flagship and use rdpwrap to make windows 7 support multi-session logins.  What bothers me is that windows7 doesn't have the CAL manager that windows server does.  So I do not know how to solve the CAL exception message prompted by xfreerdp.  I think this is still essentially a question about rdpwarp, and I'd like to hear it answered.

Comment: Subverting the single-client nature of Windows to support multiple client sessions is an unsupported hack, so dangerous to rely upon. I have not understood correctly your reference to rdwrap, but I advise searching for another solution for your server.